# Kibana while updating role I'm getting this error "applications is not allowed"?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, kibana-4, kibana-5

When I try to update an existing role with some indexes I'm getting the "applications" is not allowed

[image: See the error below]

Comment: Do you see anything in logs at all ?

Comment: nope I havent seen any logs.

Comment: Sorry cant think of anything other than deleting and re-creating the role if possible

Comment: In that case I need to re-create the role every single time I try to update which is not a good Idea ! Can you tell where will the root cause if u know ?

Comment: You can use your browser ‘developer tools’ to see if Elasticsearch is sending back any meaningful error in the response section. Open browser developer tools and update the role again and see the response from ES